# How to parse content loaded by javascript after the dom is complete

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, dynamic

I have been working on parsing some of the data from the wow armory and have come into a bit of a snag.  When it comes to the site serving up the achievements that players have received, it uses javascript to intemperate a string such as `#73:1283` to display the requested information.  (I made this number up but the data for the requests are formated like this).

1. Is it possible to pull data from a page that requires javascript to display its data with php?
2. How do you parse data from a site that has been loaded after the dom is ready or complete using php?

Comment: Can you give us a code example of what it is doing? Otherwise, in order to fully understand what you are asking, we'd have to look through all the WoW Armory code ourselves to figure out what you mean. Is the site loading data asynchronously after the page loads? Or does it make an AJAX call when you click on something? Are you sure it's Javascript itself that's interpreting the string, rather than just sending a request to aserver somewhere?

Comment: `http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement#96:14861` is a sample link you can go to to check out what I am talking about.  If you disable javascript you will only be able to pull `http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement`  From this page, all of the menu on the left that has to do with Achievements are loaded into the dom with out the use of html.  You will not be able to use the menu with out javascript enabled but the data for the complete menu is there.

Comment: The issue is that you cannot load the content which corresponds the the menue items with out the use of javascript.  I will admit that I am not the most skilled JS person but looking at the source tells me that it uses a combination of jquery and there own in house JS to interpret the links.  I was not able to determine where it pulls the data from based on looking at the JS.

Comment: `loadModule: function(key) {
  var module = $('#sidebar-'+ key);

  if (module.length > 0) {
   $.ajax({
    url: Core.baseUrl +'/sidebar/'+ key,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    global: false,
    success: function(data) {
     if (data)
      module.html(data);
     else
      module.remove();
    },
    error: function() {
     module.remove();
    }
   });
  }
 }
`

Comment: If i had to guess, I would say that is where it is pulling the data from but like I said I do not know JS all that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Firebug, I was able to look at the HTTP headers to see what AJAX calls were being made to generate the content on these pages: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement#96:14861 and http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement#96

It looks the page is making an asynchronous call to load this page: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement/14861 when the part after the hash is 96:14861, and a call to http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement/96 when the part after the hash is just 96. Both of those pages return XML that can be parsed to render HTML.

So generally speaking, if there's just one number after the hash, just put `http://.../achievement/<number here>` as the URL. If there are two numbers, put the second number at the end of the URL instead.

What you'll need to do, rather than pulling the Javascript and interpreting it, is make HTTP requests to those URLs by yourself in PHP (using cURL, for example) and parse the data on your own.

I would really recommend learning JavaScript and jQuery, since it will be very hard for you to really build a good site that pulls information from the WoW Armory without understanding all the AJAX loads that are going on in the background.

Comment: I had not had a chance to get back to this yet but you are correct.  My findings are the same as yours.  Thank you for the detailed response.  I was able to parse the menues which contain all of the information needed to find the corresponding page.  I understand enough javascript to use jquery and get around a bit but I am still using server side php to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend seeing if you can replicate the query sent by JavaScript in PHP. While I don't believe there is a way to process JavaScript in PHP, there definitely isn't a simple or scalable way.

I would attempt to scan the first page's source that you downloaded with PHP for strings of that format you mention. Then if the JS on their site is querying something like http://www.wow.com/armory.php?id=#72:1284 you can just download the source of that next. You can find out how the JS is querying the server with something like FireBug or the Inspector in Chrome or Safari.

So in summary:

1. Check to find the JS URL format and if you can replicate it.
2. Create PHP to get main page and extract all strings.
3. Create PHP to loop through these strings and get these pages (with URL that JS requests).
4. Do whatever you wanted to with that information.

Comment: `http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement#96:14861`  Is a link to what I am working with.  If you disable javascript you will not be able to use the menu on the left that corresponds to the achievements nor will you be able to retrieve the data that corresponds to each menu item.  I am not very skilled with JS so i was not able to determine where the JS gets the requested pages from.

Comment: It looks like the data for that URL comes from `http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/glitchshot/achievement/14861`. So you should be able to take the part of the URL after the `:` and remove the `#XX` and get the information you are looking for programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery's $(document).onready function which helps
to run java script code when the web page loads up.

ex

```
<div id="wowoData">#4325325</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
$("#wowoData").css("border","1px solid red");
}

)
</script>
```

Comment: As it sits rite now, I am parsing the page in PHP.  I have considered using JS to assist the PHP in parsing some of the content but, I am not that skilled with JS and I am trying to leave the thinking to the server side environment.